# "Access violation" при вызове lstrcpynW

Tags: c++, winapi

```
    //FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *fni;
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:

                        ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
                            &fni,
                            1024,
                            FALSE,
                            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
                            &gf,
                            NULL,
                            NULL);


                        // WinAPI функция для копирования Unicode строки
                        lstrcpynW(buffer, fni->FileName, fni->FileNameLength/2);

                        std::cout << "File " << buffer << " changed\n";
     break;
```

C++ + WinAPI
Проблема в функции `lstrcpynW(buffer, fni->FileName, fni->FileNameLength/2);`
При использовании вылетает программа с ошибкой в окошке вида:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00A664A3 in WatcherWinAPI.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000008.

Пробовал разные функция для преобразования из юникода, все выдают подобную ошибку. Никогда раньше не сталкивался. Использую *Visual Studio 2015*

Comment: покажите где и как Вы инициализируете `buffer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по сообщению, указатель `fni` указывает на адрес `0x00000000`, т.е. является нулевым указателем. Тем не менее вы смело читаете через него данные. Все, разумеется, сразу накрывается медным тазом.

Но ошибка произрастает совсем из другого места и никакого отношения к `lstrcpynW` не имеет. Согласно документации, второй параметр `ReadDirectoryChangesW` - это указатель на буфер, в который `ReadDirectoryChangesW` будет складывать информацию. Вы же передаете туда *указатель на указатель* `fni` (???) и при этом еще и врете, что передали указатель на буфер размером `1024`. Вы, похоже, ожидаете, что `ReadDirectoryChangesW` сама для вас как-то выделит память под буфер.

`ReadDirectoryChangesW` этого не делает. Выделение памяти - ваша задача. Это вы обязаны заранее выделить память для буфера и передать указатель на него и его точный размер в `ReadDirectoryChangesW`.

Вызов `ReadDirectoryChangesW` должен выглядеть примерно так

```
  BYTE fni_buffer[1024];
  DWORD gf;

  BOOL ok = ReadDirectoryChangesW(hDir,
                                  (LPVOID) fni_buffer,
                                  sizeof fni_buffer,
                                  FALSE,
                                  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
                                  &gf,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL);

  if (ok && gf > 0)
  {
    const BYTE *fni_origin = fni_buffer;
    const FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *fni;

    do
    {
      fni = (const FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *) fni_origin;

      // Делайте, что хотите с `fni`

      fni_origin += fni->NextEntryOffset;
    } while (fni->NextEntryOffset > 0)
  }
```

Comment: В ошибке адрес 0x00000008, но сути это не меняет, да.

Comment: @ixSci: Ошибка, очевидно, возникла при попытке доступа к полю `fni->FileNameLength`, которое располагается по смещению `0x8` в структуре `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION`. Именно из этого я и сделал вывод о том, что само `fni` равно `0x0`